# ASP.NET Web-Application Architectures / Patterns

Tags: asp.net, architecture, web-applications

Does anybody knows good, short and slim **tutorials**, which describe actual/modern web-application **architectures** / **patterns** (especially for ASP.NET based (classic and MVC) applications (maybe also with embedded Silverlight components) ?
How would you you design today an **ASP.NET** application which uses different datasources (databases, services,...) ?
Background: I has been away a couple of years writing web applications, and I want to start now again. So at the moment I am a little bit unsure, how to take off and find the right starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take reference of following  -

http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in MVC I'd suggest starting out with the offical MS tutorials:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

Answer (score 2):

There happens to be an upcoming free online conference on ASP .NET MVC that may interest you:  http://mvcconf.com/

Answer (score 2):

Check out Sharp Architecture:
http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net

there are some articles that describe how & why it's architected the way it is that might help you with your project.

Answer (score 0):

You have many questions embedded in one :)

1. short and slim tutorials = For getting architectures/patterns explanation is always bit more extensive since original developer/reviewer explains the design decisions or thought process of selection of components used.
2. I would like to recommend  P&P's Application Architecture Guide (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650706.aspx) for reference architectures.
3. Real World Coding Examples: There are lot many on GitHub. It really depends on the type of app you are taken for development and business domain. 
   Some pointers: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/samples, NopCommerce,http://www.magelia.org/,www.teamlab.com etc. There is lot of good codebase which is working and available on GitHub etc.

PS: Start with www.asp.net Best resource!

Hope this helps.